# What is the default username and password for the Cisco SPA-942?

Tags: cisco, voip, linksys

I can't seem to find the default admin username and password for the web administration interface for the Linksys/Cisco SPA-942 VoIP phone. What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/voice_ip_comm/csbpipp/ip_phones/administration/guide/spa_wip_admin.pdf) there aren't any passwords by default.

```
NOTE: No default passwords are assigned to
either the Administrator or User accounts. Only
the Administrator account can assign and
change passwords
```

By default, the Administrator account name is `admin`, and the User
account name is `user`.

Comment: Thanks, but blank or just admin isn't working. I've contacted the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

For those using this phone from RingCentral: RingCentral sets the admin account information and doesn't release it. I'll mark LukeR's answer as the correct one.